# add subview to subclassed UITextField not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, subclass, subview

I have subclassed a `UITextField` and trying to add a subview by calling `[self.superView addSubview:newView]` but this is not working and `self.superview.class` returns `null`.

How can one add a subview to the `superView`

The view is showing on the screen and done using Storyboard

```
@interface NewTextField : UITextField <UITextFieldDelegate>


@end
```

and then

```
@implementation MBTextField


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self addWhiteLine]; // here im adding a view 
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)addWhiteLine{

    UIView *div = [UIView new];
    div.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                           self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height+borderWidth,
                           self.frame.size.width,
                           borderWidth);

    div.backgroundColor = [borderColor colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3f];
    [self.superview addSubview:div];

}
```

---

**Solution**: accepted answer and comments by @mackworth. Frame of the view had to be changed to following.

```
    div.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                           self.frame.size.height - borderWidth,
                           self.frame.size.width,
                           borderWidth);
```

Comment: At the time you call `addWhiteLine`, the text field hasn't been added to a view yet.

Comment: And it's bad to have this custom view add a view to something other than itself. Now you have to be sure to remove the other view as well as move the other view as `self` is moved around. Just add the subview to `self` to keep it simple.

Comment: Why are you adding newly created view to textfield's superview rather than adding it as a subview of textfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `self.superview` is nil, then at the time `addWhiteLine` is being called, self hasn't been added to the view hierarchy yet. This actually makes sense given that you're calling it from the `initWithCoder`. Whoever's loading this view has to `alloc`/`init` before adding it to a superview.  As a fix, why add to `self.superview`, shouldn't you add to `self` instead?

Edit: As discussed in comments, another problem is that the line is being drawn outside the frame, so it should be `self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height-borderWidth` instead.

Comment: adding to self is also not showing anything on the screen. I made it significantly higher height and still nothing.

Comment: origin.y+height+borderWidth will take you off the bottom of the frame, no?  http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/view_frames_bounds.html

Comment: I think your comment is key to solution. It jumps outside the text field frame which is why I was trying to add to superview. If I keep in frame it overlaps the text in the textField. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's your goal for the line? if you want it at the bottom of the field, then it should be self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height-borderWidth, but is that what overlaps the text?